# sas hash table with multiple key value pairs

Tags: sas, hashtable

I have a lookup table which looks like this (Name: LOOKUP_TABLE):

```
Obs  Member_id   plan_id    Plan_desc       group_id    Group_name
1   164-234      XYZ        HMO_Salaried    G123      Umbrellas, Inc.
2   297-123      ABC        PPO_Hourly      G123      Umbrellas, Inc.
3   344-123      JKL        HMO_Executive   G456      Toy Company
4   395-123      XYZ        HMO_Salaried    G123      Umbrellas, Inc.
5   495-987      ABC        PPO_Hourly      G456      Toy Company
6   562-987      ABC        PPO_Hourly      G123      Umbrellas, Inc.
7   697-123      XYZ        HMO_Salaried    G456      Toy Company
```

I have another table with the following data (Name: MAIN_TABLE):

```
Obs  Member_id   zip       income   svc_dt      dx    plan_id group_id Obs old_id new_id
1    164-234    04021      $45,000  2005/01/01  250   XYZ     G123      1 164-234 N164-234
2    297-123    22003-1234 $56,999  2005/02/03  4952  ABC     G123      2 297-123 N297-123
3    344-123    45459-0306 $72,999  2005/03/15  78910 JKL     G456      3 344-123 C344-123
4    395-123    03755      $75,000  2005/04/14  250   XYZ     G123      4 N164-234 M164-234
5    495-987    94305      $96,000  2005/08/19  12345 ABC     G456      5 N297-123 B297-123 
6    562-987    78277-8310 $32,999  2005/09/13  250   ABC     G123      6 M164-234 P164-234
7    697-123    88044-3760 $47,999  2005/11/01  4952  XYZ     G456      7 P164-234 A164-234
```

My SAS data step is as follows:

```
data MAIN_TABLE_1.
set MAIN_TABLE;
declare hash pd_lookup(dataset:"&LOOKUP_TABLE.");
            rc_pd_definekey = pd_lookup.definekey 
                (
                    'plan_id', 
                    'group_id'
                );
            rc_pd_definedata = pd_lookup.definedata 
                (
                    'Plan_desc', 
                    'Group_name'
                );
            rc_pd_definedone = pd_lookup.definedone();
             call missing (
                Plan_desc, 
                Group_name
            );
            put "rc_pd_definekey is "  rc_pd_definekey;
            put "rc_pd_definedata is " rc_pd_definedata;
            put "rc_pd_definedone is " rc_pd_definedone;
            drop rc_pd_definekey rc_pd_definedata rc_pd_definedone;
            rc_pd_lookup  = pd_lookup.find();

            run
```

My question is to understand whats happening behind the scenes in this lookup, mainly with regards to the key value pairs being generated.
i.e., are there individual key value pairs being generated.
As in , the example of key value pairs will be

: "plan_id" -> "Plan_desc"

: "plan_id" -> "Group_name"

: "group_id" -> "Plan_desc"

: "group_id" -> "Group_name"

Or is it that the keys are concatenated together and so are the values, and then we make pairs.
As in, something like this

:"plan_id"+"group_id" -> "Plan_desc" + "Group_name"

I ask this question as I have to convert the same code logic into R, and if I misunderstand, then the whole R code will be wrong

Comment: Your data step code will not work, as currently written - it contains references to two more hash objects `lgd_lookup` and `ead_lookup`, that are not declared.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out and sorry about that. It was a typo. I should have been more careful as I was replicating an original script used in my organization and somehow those two lines seeped in mistakenly. I have edited out those lines now.
My main aim is to understand the process in order to replicate the logic in R.

Comment: I am shamelessly asking to remove the downvote as it limits my capabilites to ask questions on this forum. Lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each combination of `plan_id` and `group_id` is used to retrieve a unique entry from the hash table containing values of both `plan_desc` and `group_name`.

However, currently there are duplicate rows with the same combination of these ids in the lookup table, which may cause errors or unexpected behaviour - e.g. obs 1 and 4. You should create a deduplicated copy of the lookup table and use that to declare the hash object.

Comment: So does that mean that there will be combinations of `plan_id` and `group_id`, but not combinations of `plan_desc` and `group_desc` ?

Comment: For each unique combination of ids in the hash there will only be one set of lookup values, unless you are using [some very specific hash techniques](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings16/10200-2016.pdf).